# Splitting multiple csv files based on the length in a folder using python

Tags: python, list, loops

I need to split csv files based on the length of the file. This has to be done on multiple csv files in the folder. The code below is splitting only one file in the folder. The code is shown below. Can someone tell me why I am not getting the desired output

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Office\Data1\*.csv'

for filenames in glob.glob(path):

   csvfile = open(filenames, 'r').readlines()
   filename = 1
   for i in range(len(csvfile)):
       if i % 1190 == 0:
           open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+').writelines(csvfile[i:i+1190])
           filename += 1
```

Comment: You set filename=1 in every iteration of the outer loop thus overwriting the "split" files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "filename = 1". every time you enter the loop with a new filenames (not a great name for a single file name btw) you call the first section "1.csv" so this will over write the existing "1.csv" from the previous run.

Here is an example for a solution to your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Office\Data1\*.csv'

for filename in glob.glob(path):

   csvfile = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
   filename_section = 1
   for i in range(len(csvfile)):
       if i % 1190 == 0:
           open("".join([filename.split(".")[0], "_", str(filename_section), '.csv']), 'w+').writelines(csvfile[i:i+1190])
           filename_section += 1
```

Example file from output:

test.csv -> test_1.csv, test_2.csv ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked perfectly. I will take care of naming conventions in the future.

Comment: don't forget to vote up so who ever searches this post will find a good answer :)